# Extract more objects from an array stored in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

```
import "./App.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as L from "leaflet";

function App() {
  const markerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl:
      "https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-green.png", //change icon color to grey
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowUrl:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
  });

  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState(null);
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState(null); // add a new state to store the filtered list
  const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null); //map reference stored in state to call the API from leaflet

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountryList(data);
        setFilteredCountries(data); // set the initial value of filteredCountries to be equal to countryList
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error:", err));
  }, []);
  function filterItems(countryList, query) {
    return countryList.filter(
      (el) => el.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) //filters out the names from the fetch API into a new function
    );
  }

  function zoomCountryMap(latlng, filteredCountries) {
    const marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(mapRef); // Create a new marker at the specified latlng coordinates'

    const popup = L.popup().setContent(`<p>${filteredCountries}</p>`);
    marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();

    mapRef.setView(latlng, 6);
  }
  //console.log(filteritems);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by country..."
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
          padding: "1em",
          paddingLeft: "2.5em",
          fontSize: "16px",
          backgroundImage:
            "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)",
          backgroundSize: "2.5em 2.5em",
          backgroundPosition: "12em center",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilteredCountries(filterItems(countryList, e.target.value));
          console.log(filterItems(countryList, e.target.value));
        }}
      />

      <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "700px", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <table id="country">
          <thead>
            <tr className="sticky-heading">
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Country
              </th>
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Capital
              </th>
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Region
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {filteredCountries ? ( // check if filteredCountryList is not null
              filteredCountries.map(
                (
                  table // iterate over the filtered list
                ) => (
                  <tr
                    key={table.name.common}
                    onClick={() =>
                      zoomCountryMap(
                        //this function is called with 3 arguments
                        table.latlng,
                        table.name.common,
                        table.region
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <td>{table.name.common}</td>
                    <td>{table.capital}</td>
                    <td>{table.region}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              )
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan="3">Search for country...</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <MapContainer
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={3}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        whenReady={({ target }) => setMapRef(target)}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
        />
        {/* {countryList &&
          countryList.map((markers) => (
            <Marker
              key={markers.name.common}
              position={[markers.latlng[0], markers.latlng[1]]} //iterate over countrylist and mapping out the markers
              icon={markerIcon}
            >
              <Popup>
                <h1> {markers.name.common} </h1>
                <h3>
                  <p> Capital: {markers.capital}</p>
                  <p> Region: {markers.region}</p>
                  <p> Subregion: {markers.subregion}</p>
                  <p>
                    {" "}
                    Currencies:{" "}
                    {Object.keys(markers.currencies ?? {}) // looping trough all currencies, then getting name from    object in value

                      .map((key) => markers.currencies[key]["name"])
                      .join(", ")}{" "}
                  </p>
                </h3>
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          ))} */}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my total code, and I'm struggling quite massive with this one function

```
  function zoomCountryMap(latlng, filteredCountries) {
    const marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(mapRef); // Create a new marker at the specified latlng coordinates'

    const popup = L.popup().setContent(`<p>${filteredCountries}</p>`);
    marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();

    mapRef.setView(latlng, 6);
  }
```

in this function i want to access more data from filteredcountries (API stored) to the popup, like the capital, flag image etc. But I can't figured it out.

im completely new to javascript so any help is good. Ive tried to access the data with passing arguments, indexing and so on. since I already have the data stored in filteredcountries, it should not be neccessary to iterate over the API again?

what is the best solution here?

I think i need to do something with this function, but i' not 100% sure.

```
  function filterItems(countryList, query) {
    return countryList.filter(
      (el) => el.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) //filters out the names from the fetch API into a new function
    );
```

I think im struggling a bit with datatypes and how to access them properly

im completely new to javascript so any help is good. Ive tried to access the data with passing arguments, indexing and so on. since I already have the data stored in filteredcountries, it should not be neccessary to iterate over the API again?

Comment: `filteredItmers` function seems working correctly

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5LMqX4m.png Isn't this what you need?

Comment: ye sorry, bad desc of the problem.

what i want: the zoomfunction, after zooming the popup should display the country image, and maybe capital of the country and so on. but I cant see how I should access it. the whole API is stored in multiple states

Comment: https://9s550b.csb.app/ please have a look at this

Comment: Please check again, does it work as you need?

Comment: ye i can see a img file dere, but it wont render completely.-. but how did you manage to get that data?

Comment: You passed wrong value to useState for the initial value

Comment: `const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState([])`

Comment: What do you mean by `wont' render completely`?`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1eGXsWh.png I have set the height: 50vh

Comment: in the popup i want the flag of hong kong to appear. what you mean the wrong value?
 const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState(null);
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState(null); // add a new state to store the filtered list
  const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null)

I cant see anything wrong here? the app is working perfectly as is, but I want to fetch the country flag too, inside the popup. and I cant figure out how :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250606/discussion-between-dream-bold-and-brede).